# iOS swift, When touchesEnded called in UIView, presencetViewController other xib or ViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'd like to presentViewController when touchedEnded function called in xib but I have no idea how to implement it.

Here is part of my project.

// ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // add custom xib view (day view)
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ScheduleView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ScheduleView
        view.frame = self.view.frame

        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }


}
```

// ScheduleView.swift

```
class ScheduleView.swift: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        print("touchesBegan")
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        print("touchesEnd")

        // move scene in here
        // show secondViewController
    }



}
```

// secondeViewController.swift

```
class secondeViewController.swift: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only view controller can present another view controller.
You can use delegation pattern to do so.

Create a new protocol

```
protocol PresentVCDelegate {
    func presentVC()
}
```

Add a property in ScheduleView

```
var presentVCDelegate: PresentVCDelegate
```

In your ViewController, conform to this protocol and set the View's delegate as self

```
//in view will appear
view.presentVCDelegate = self
```

Don't forget to conform to the protocol

```
extension ViewController: PresentVCDelegate {
    func presentVC() {
        //present your secondViewController here
    }
}
```

and finally in your touchEnd method inside ScheduleView, call the delegate method

```
self.presentVCDelegate.presentVC()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I do.

```
// ViewController.swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // add custom xib view (day view)
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ScheduleView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ScheduleView
        view.frame = self.view.frame

        //in view will appear
        view.presentVCDelegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }


}

extension ViewController: PresentVCDelegate {
    func presentVC() {
        //present your secondViewController here
    }
}

// ScheduleView.swift

protocol PresentVCDelegate {
    func presentVC()
}

class ScheduleView: UIView {
    var presentVCDelegate: PresentVCDelegate
    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        print("touchesBegan")
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        print("touchesEnd")

        // move scene in here
        // show secondViewController

    }



}

// secondeViewController.swift

class secondeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }


}
```